# How to iterate over multiple images of different dimensions and stack them into a single picture horizontally?

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv, concatenation

I have a multiple pictures with different dimensions. I have been trying to concat them horizontally using openCV.

The process is kind of following:

- Iterate over all the images to find the max width and total height.
- Create a black mask that is with the size of max width and total height got from all the images.
- Stack all the images horizontally on that black mask.

I am not sure how to do this thing. Kindly help me!

Comment: Can you iterate over all images? Can you find the width and height of a given image? Can you find the sum of a list of numbers? Can you find the maximum of a list of numbers?

Comment: I can iterate over all the images from a data path using cv2.imread. But I am not sure how to do the rest! Thank you!

Comment: You will have to pad or crop them to the same dimensions first.

Answer (score 0):

Images are just 3D matrices, so you can do this very easily by creating a matrix of zeros (= black) of the desired size, then filling in your images.

I've created fake images here but you can use cv2 to read in your real images.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# create three images of different shapes and different shades of grey
img1 = np.ones((100, 200, 3), dtype=int)*50
img2 = np.ones((200, 400, 3), dtype=int)*100
img3 = np.ones((100, 300, 3), dtype=int)*150

imgs = [img1, img2, img3]

# get max width and total height
max_width = 0
total_height = 0
for img in imgs:
    total_height += img.shape[0]
    max_width = max(max_width, img.shape[1])

# make black canvas of appropriate shape
canvas = np.zeros((total_height, max_width, 3), dtype=int)

# stack images on canvas
start_height = 0
for img in imgs:
    print(img.shape)
    canvas[start_height:start_height+img.shape[0], 0:img.shape[1], :] = img
    start_height+= img.shape[0]

# show results
plt.imshow(canvas)
```

This produces the following result:
[image: plot of stacked images]